# How can I figure out what's causing my PS3 to start, and stop it?

Tags: ps3

Yesterday, my power randomly went out while my PS3 was on. It was just sitting their idle on the main screen, wasn't in a game. When I turned it back on, it went through all its hard drive checks, etc. I'm not sure if this is related, but this didn't start happening until immediately after the power outage.

Anyways, I can't seem to keep my PS3 turned off without actually removing the power from it by flipping the power switch on the back. Every time I turn off my PS3 either by [Users] > [Turn Off System] or the power button on the front, it will automatically start back up on its own a few seconds later.

Is there any way I can figure out why it's doing this or what's causing it, and how can I stop it?

Comment: Myself and another friend have both experienced similar issues with our PS3 randomly turning on for no reason.  I just always assumed, I accidentally sat on the remote.  :-P

Comment: Is the PS3 usable while it's on? If so, perhaps it's time to backup your saves (to USB and/or cloud) and give Sony support a call.

Comment: I agree with @YellowMegaMan but also check you don't have any software running in the background. My PlayTV would turn my Playstation on at random times even though it wasn't plugged in and would just sit there not doing anything.

Comment: +1 for checking the remote. Also, check if your ps3 is set to wake by network (used in remote play). One last thing to try is stopping auto updates if you have that enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this by resetting all the PS3 settings and all the controllers. It's not the greatest thing reconfiguring everything for your PS3, but at least it doesn't delete any game or save data.

Apparently the PS3 kept thinking it was receiving a signal when there was no signal being sent, like it was trapped in there constantly trying to connect something that wasn't there. After the power outage, I tried to start my PS3 via the controller but it didn't work. Then when I started the PS3 via the power button on the front (moments later), the controller turned itself off and I had to attempt to reconnect it again. Weird issues, all is good now though.